# AsyncContext and I/O error create CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat8, servlet-3.0

sometimes when I flush the response Outputstream.
I'm having `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out` or other IO exception and multiple CLOSE_WAIT stats. 
the thing is, the client closes the connection and the server doesn't.
I tried to close response Outputstream but CLOSE_WAIT still shown.

I would like to close the connection on the server side in case the client closed the connection. How to handle it?

In any case of an IO exception in asyncContext, I remove the asyncContext to be used again and `asyncContext.complete()`